# No output when class is created

Tags: c++, class, methods, constructor

Why does this code

```
class A
{
public:
    A()
    {
        cout<<"Class A!";
    }
    A(int a=0)
    {
        cout<<"A";
    }
};

int main()
{
    A a();
    return 0;
}
```

... result in no output?

But if instead of `A a()` I place any value, then the output is "A". And I can't just simply type `A a` because it says it's ambiguous.

Comment: Why isn't it a duplicate exactly? You're asking why you get no output. The output is in your class constructor, which is not getting called. The reason why is in the duplicate - you're not creating an object of that class.

Comment: Write `A a;` instead of `A a();` BTW: Your code is broken, because both of your constructors can be called without args. That is not possible!

Comment: I know, it was just a tricky thing I saw in a quiz and didn't know why there's no output.

Comment: You get no output because you did not create an object. You simply define a function a which returns an object of type A. All that is written in the linked duplicate!